# KDE5 -- bring up the "command prompt" like bar at the top of the screen

Tags: shortcut-keys, execute-command, kde5

I don't remember what it's called, but I just found myself in a situation where I could use it.

Answer (score 2):

It's called **KRunner**, but you'll find the shortcut settings in

**System Settings > Workspace > Shortcuts > Global Shortcuts > Run Command**:

[image: Where to find Run Command]

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is the default binding. You can also open it by executing `krunner`, e.g. in a terminal.

Comment: Alt+F2 also the default as you see.

Comment: @Gannet I think it is only default in Kubuntu. When I expand it, it shows `None` as default for Global Alternative and `Alt+F2` as custom.

Comment: Possibly you're right as I'm using Kubuntu and I didn't check any other Ubuntu derivatives with KDE.

Comment: Both `Alt+Space` and `Alt+F2` work (as defaults) on Kubuntu (18.04).